# angular typescript interface default value

Tags: angular, typescript

My interface :

```
export interface MapMarker{
    longitude: number,
    latitude: number,
    popupText: string
}
```

My component

```
mapMarker: MapMarker;

ngOnInit() {
    this.mapMarker.latitude = location.coords.latitude;
    this.mapMarker.longitude = location.coords.longitude;
    this.mapMarker.popupText = "Your current Location"
  }
```

this tells me that can't set latitude of undefined. I know why is that. It's because mapMarker has a type MapMarker but is undefined, because it's undefined by default. What should I do? if I try `mapMarker: MapMarker = null;` still wrong.

I also tried  `mapMarker: MapMarker = {};` which gives me following error = `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MapMarker': longitude, latitude, popupText`

I need the solution, but i don't want to use 'any' type.

Comment: What TS is telling you *is correct*, an empty object isn't a MapMarker. Why not create the object in that method too?

Comment: then i still have to use any.

Comment: let data = {}; data.latitude = location.coords.latitude; this is also the error. so let data:any = {}; this works. but it's bad.

Comment: Why don't you include the properties when you create it?

Comment: then why the hell do I need interface at all? :D

Comment: So the compiler can tell you what it's telling you now? So that other things using that property can be type-safe?

Comment: I would use class instead of interface in this situation, and add `this.mapMarker = new MapMarker()` at the beginning of `ngOnInit`

Comment: I suggest you use a class, you won't have to initialize anything outside of it, you just call new and your properties will be initialized to their default values

Comment: Why are you setting the current location onInit() if you don’t have location data anyway? If you have your reasons then I’d suggest using async ngOnInit and await a function that gets current location

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't want to create an object and assign default values every time, use a class with default values for its properties instead. If you don't specify the values, defaults values will be used according to your property types.

```
export class MapMarker {
    longitude: number = 0;
    latitude: number = 0;
    popupText: string = '';
}
```

Then you can simply create an instance of your class and every field will be correctly initialized:

```
mapMarker: MapMarker = new MapMarker();
```

If you want to keep your interface, just implement it in the class:

```
export interface IMapMarker {
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;
    popupText: string;
}

export class MapMarker implements IMapMarker {
    longitude: number = 0;
    latitude: number = 0;
    popupText: string = '';
}
```

If some of your properties are optional, use the optional operator for them:

```
export interface IMapMarker {
    longitude?: number;
    latitude?: number;
    popupText?: string;
}
```

But then, you will always have to make sure the property is not null before using it.

Answer (score 3):

> Classes and interfaces are powerful structures that facilitate not
>   just object-oriented programming but also type-checking in TypeScript.
>   A class is a blueprint from which we can create objects that share the
>   same configuration properties and methods. An interface is a group of
>   related properties and methods that describe an object, but neither
>   provides implementation nor initialization for them.
>
> Since both of these structures define what an object looks like, both
>   can be used in TypeScript to type our variables. The decision to use a
>   class or an interface truly depends on our use case: type-checking
>   only, implementation details (typically via creating a new instance),
>   or even both! We can use classes for type-checking and the underlying
>   implementation
>
> if you are interested only in type-checking the responses Interface is
>   a good choice Furthermore, an interface is a virtual structure that
>   only exists within the context of TypeScript. The TypeScript compiler
>   uses interfaces solely for type-checking purposes. Once your code is
>   transpiled to its target language, it will be stripped from its
>   interfaces - JavaScript isn’t typed, there’s no use for them there.
>
> **Since interfaces do not exist in runtime there is no runtime cost!**

Regarding the issue you are facing:
**Use this**

```
mapMarker: MapMarker={longitude: 0,latitude: 0, popupText: ''};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options:

1 Make every property of MapMarker optional

```
export interface MapMarker{
   longitude?: number,
   latitude?: number,
   popupText?: string
}
```

2 Use class

```
export class MapMarker {
    longitude: number = 0;
    latitude: number = 0;
    popupText: string = '';
}
```

3 Just use a plain object with default value

```
mapMarker: MapMarker =  {
    longitude: number = 0;
    latitude: number = 0;
    popupText: string = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` for optional properties in typescript like following. I hope this is what you want.

```
export interface MapMarker{
    longitude?: number,
    latitude?: number,
    popupText?: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make use of **Type Assertion** like below

```
mapMarker: MapMarker = {} as MapMarker;
```

or

```
mapMarker: MapMarker = <MapMarker>{};
```

This will tell the TypeScript compiler to treats this empty object `{}` as an object of `MapMarker` interface.

*Note that this will just prevent you from compile-time error, not runtime.*

Eventually, you have to add properties (i.e. latitude, longitude etc.) in your variable `mapMarker` before those properties are being used by rest part of the application.